# Referential CCK types in Joomla?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

Using Joomla! 3.0 (Or 2.5, whatever works best), I'm needing to create a system comprised of three entity types:

Artists -- Name, country of origin, links to social media/website, etc.
Set -- Start time, end time, description
Venue -- Name, description

Hierarchically, it would look like this: `Venue > Set > Artist`. A venue will have multiple sets, and the sets will have one or more artists.

I initially wanted to do this in Drupal, which has modules like [EntityReference](http://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) that allow you to reference arbitrary nodes. So far, it seems like Zoo and K2 are the two main content construction kits for Joomla!, but after playing around with both for a while, it seems like neither has fields to reference other content. Am I missing something?

I'll ultimately want to create a daily calendar of sets/artists, so ideas towards how I'd do that are also appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying that you want something like the core article link insert button but that allows other kinds of content?

Comment: @Elin -- Essentially, yes. It'd be great if it does something more than that, though: it'd be nice if I can create bonafide, database-driven relations between content, such that I can build a query to list all venues and am then able extend that to pull in all sets and/or artists related to that venue.

Comment: well it might not be what you want but you could look at some code i posted to the feature tracker the other day

http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/joomla/tracker/?action=TrackerItemEdit&tracker_item_id=29854

Comment: @Elin -- Not quite, but that looks really cool, might take a closer look at it later!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In FlexiContent <kbd>[External link](http://www.flexicontent.org/)</kbd> you have the Universal Module where you can scope (filter) by Related, Tag, Categories, almost everything. Works with 2.5. Install the latest svn version and go to the modules to see how powerful this component can be. 
Here you can see how many custom fields <kbd>[this site](http://j.mp/RghpCh)</kbd> are been used: pagination, image gallery, related, most viewed. Because it is so powerful it can be hard to handle at the first time. Great forum support.

**EDIT 25-09-2013:**
Is now almost 8 months after my answer and the project has evolved a lot. Now you have Advanced Search, Per field permissions and translations, now you have a FILTER MODULE where you can select how you want to search inside your items.

A lot of design tweaks front-end and back-end. Now the 2.1 version is almost here with great news.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was using J!3.0, which is why I hadn't tried FlexiContent or SEBLOD. I'll give that a shot.

Comment: are you using this in a production site? you shouldn't the stable release only comes out in september. just a suggestion but you already must know this. also the components for 3.0 are not stable yet.

Comment: Valid point. Any way you could compare FlexiContent with SEBLOD, as mentioned below?

Comment: @aendrew I only understand FC (Flexicontent) and nothing about SL(Seblod). I know that SL is very powerful, it has been in the community for years now and I usually see very complex sites done in SL, they have the free download, just install it in a demo site and give it a try. About FC only in the last 2 years they became an active community, still very powerful and maybe easier to handle. Usually to select an component I list the minimum requirements I need and then I'll try the 3 best components, ex: multi-lingual, image gallery, pagination, related, SEO Tags, permission per category, etc.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you miss SEBLOD CCK, like Elin who know it...
You are able to link different content types by Related article field type and do join queries with search type. We have some other relation types. Contact us directly to know more. I remember that Fabrik and Mighty Ressource hace somethink lile that but not for the search.
K2 and Zoo are not most popular CCK, it s true only for K2. But K2 is not really a CCK, more an advanced content manager, it s not flexible and you can not build real application.
Best Regards

Comment: See above. I was using 3x, so maybe I'll do a 2.5x testing install with SEBLOD and FlexiContent later on. Any thoughts on how those two projects differ? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Zoo have a lot of field kinds, two of them are "Related Item" and "Related Category". Both can relate other content of your zoo app.

http://yootheme.com/zoo/documentation/elements/related-items

If this is not enough for you, Zoolanders have an element called "Related Items Pro" (and "Related Category Pro"). Them can relate content of your zoo app and other apps in the same website.

https://www.zoolanders.com/extensions/related-items-pro

Answer (score 0):

FYI - there is also Cobalt CCK made by [MintJoomla](http://www.mintjoomla.com). **Cobalt v7** branch is for Joomla 2.5 only. It is **completely FREE now**. This includes ALL previous commercial add-ons! You will find unique features for content relations i.e. Parent/Child fields, ReadAlso field, Types as comments etc.

[C7 Package download is here](http://www.mintjoomla.com/download/joomla-25.html).

Headsup: Cobalt v8 is for J!3.x only. (mainly free, plus some special commercial add-ons)